# PHP ini file not loading

Tags: php, curl, config

I was getting extremely weird behavior from PHP -- when using Apache or PHP's built-in server to access a webpage with a simple script:

```
$c = curl_init();
```

Everything worked perfectly. However when trying to use `curl_init` from command-line I got an error: "Call to undefined function curl_init()"

In an attempt to rectify this I tried reinstalling cURL with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo php5enmod curl
```

After this I restarted my server. Now cURL isn't even working in Apache.

I took a look at `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` and `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d` and in each of these I found a symlink to `20-curl.ini` with the contents:

```
extension=curl.so
```

Next I checked `php --ini` and got the following output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

I tried `find /usr/local/lib -name "php.ini"` and it found nothing. There **is** no php.ini in this folder... so why is it looking here? And how do I tell it to look somewhere else? And why did it work before but it's broken now? And why did apt-get and php5enmod put php.ini in /etc/php5 instead of /usr/local/lib?

I'm all sorts of confused :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone else has a similar issue, try:

```
find / -name "php"
```

To see if you have two versions of PHP installed :)

Trashed the extra version and things started behaving